# EOF/BOF Error - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving the following error when I try to query a database from an excel file:

```
Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
```

Why does this error pop up? I've tested my SQL in-database and it works without issue (I've checked 4 times that I don't have typos).

I plan on appending a specific row of this data to a listbox, and doing various other things with the rest of the data. To test my SQL, I figured I would just take this first step.

My code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Check = True
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim StrDBPath As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSQL = "SELECT [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], Sum([Heads A Issues].Downtime) AS SumOfDowntime1, IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew')) AS Crew " & _
            "FROM [Heads A] INNER JOIN [Heads A Issues] ON [Heads A].[HeadLineA ID] = [Heads A Issues].[HeadLineA ID]" & _
            " GROUP BY [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))" & _
            " HAVING ((([Heads A].[Date Entered])>=#" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 1).Value & "# And ([Heads A].[Date Entered])<=#" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 2).Value & "#) And (([Heads A Issues].Department)='" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 3).Value & "') And ((IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))) Like IIf('" & Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 4).Value & "'='all','*-Crew','" & _
            Sheets("Choices").Cells(2, 4).Value & "'))) ORDER BY [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment;"

    StrDBPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Daily Closing Report V997.accdb"
     cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                             "Data Source=" & StrDBPath & ";" & _
                             "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                             "Persist Security Info=False;"
     rst.Open strSQL, _
              cnn, adOpenStatic
     rst.MoveFirst
     With Me.ListBox1
         .Clear
         Do
             .AddItem rst![Department]
             rst.MoveNext
         Loop Until rst.EOF
     End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
     On Error Resume Next
     rst.Close
     cnn.Close
     Set rst = Nothing
     Set cnn = Nothing
     Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
     MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
     Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what line you are getting the error on I assume it is in this section

```
 rst.MoveFirst
 With Me.ListBox1
     .Clear
     Do
         .AddItem rst![Department]
         rst.MoveNext
     Loop Until rst.EOF
 End With
```

I would make these changes.

```
 If rst.recordcount > 0 then
     rst.MoveFirst
 End if
 With Me.ListBox1
     .Clear
     Do while rst.eof = false
         .AddItem rst![Department]
         rst.MoveNext
     Loop
 End With
```

I would also suggest using a lock on your recordset.  Look into adLockOptimistic and adlockpessimistic.

```
rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

To answer your last comment I would try declaring the objects different. Not that there is anything wrong with the way you did it since it didn't produce any errors. Try like this

```
Dim cnn As new adodb.connection
Dim rst As new adodb.recordset
```

This is early binding. So you can take out the set cnn=CreateObject() and set rst=CreateObject()
See if that get's you anywhere.

Comment: I apologize that I didn't specify the line. I'll try your edits!

Comment: @Ryan Welsh Welcome to stackoverflow. Let me know if the changes work.  If they do work, please accept the answer.

Comment: This did make the error go away, however the listbox isn't being populated. That is another question in itself, so I'll see what I can do and go from there. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if the recordset was eof or bof the query is not returning any records.  That brings you closer to the solution.  I would suggest displaying the strSQL in a messagebox so you can see what you are getting in your variable that you are querying.  Or you can break after it is built and display it in your immediate window if you are familiar with the IDE.

Comment: Let me know if you need help debuging that.

Comment: I've copied the output of strSQL to my clipboard and pasted it into a query w/in the database and it works just fine. So that isn't the issue, but that doesn't leave me with much else to debug. What else do you think it could be?

Comment: I just posted a bit more above about the cnn and rst declarations. If that doesn't help it may be due to the suttle sql syntax differneces between the query browser that is executing your query successfully and vba adodb. I would open a new question. In your new question just show your query coming from the strsql variable. Describe that it produces records in query browser but not from your adodb recordset.open add tags vba, sql, whatever DB you are querying, and the tag for whatever query browser you are using if there is one.