# Unexpected EOF in Excel VBA-triggered query

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I am trying to reuse a VBA macro that runs a query on a ODBC driver. The code has been serving me for months, into a different file and querying a different Database scheme (both are MySQL).

It is not working now and I don't understand why: I get EOF = 1 that (rightfully, I think) halts the macro execution.

The only EOF-related similar question I found here is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437339/eof-bof-error-excel-vba?newreg=655ea66df0b64c9ba45deddb745a4356), which I couldn't use.

This is my code: I always get the error message "Something went wrong."

```
DBAutoQuery()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Fld As ADODB.Field
Dim Col, Row As Integer
Dim ws As ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set RecSet = New ADODB.Recordset

oConn.ConnectionString = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=odbc-
staff-01.corp.booking.com;Database=staff;User=" & User & ";Password=" & Pw & 
";ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=1"

oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
oConn.Open

RecSet.Open mYsql, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If RecSet.EOF Then    
MsgBox "Something went wrong."
RecSet.Close

oConn.Close

Exit Sub
End If


Sheets(TargetSheetName).Select

Row = 1
Col = 1

For Each Fld In RecSet.Fields
ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Value = Fld.Name
Col = Col + 1
Next


RecSet.MoveFirst

Row = Row + 1

Do While Not RecSet.EOF

Col = 1

For Each Fld In RecSet.Fields
ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Value = Fld
Col = Col + 1
Next


Row = Row + 1
RecSet.MoveNext

Loop

RecSet.Close
oConn.Close

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

I went online have a grasp of what EOF is, but I don't know what its cause could be, when it's about a DB that I can query with no hassle using the very same query

For the record, the query is:

```
mYsql = "select  emp.name, emp.email, emp.off_duty, emp.jobtitle_id, 
emp.jobtitle, mgr.name, mgr.email from staff.Staff emp " & _
"join staff.Staff mgr on emp.manager_staff_id = mgr.id where 
emp.manager_staff_id in (" & List & ");"
```

And in Workbench 6.3 runs just fine. Ah, the ODBC driver tests also succeeded.

A big thank you in advance, to whomever can give me a good hint. I'm lost :-/

Alessandro

Comment: Can you ckeck if your connection is actually opened?

Comment: Try dropping the trailing `;`  Also, did you Debug.Print `mYsql` and test the output, or you tested some other version?

Comment: How is `List` defined?

Comment: Solved! Thank you all guys, you really helped me out!!

It was actually a nasty, stupid mistake in the query - that I had modified in the version I was testing on MySQL without realizing. Printing the mYsql output and testing it on the DB nailed it :-)